What bugs is in my flower and soil?

What is this bug? How do I handle it?

This is indeed a Mealybug (Family Pseudococcidae) but there are over 2000 species in that family.
The species pictured is of the genus Phenacoccus. Which contains 180 species.
But we can get even more specific! The exact species is Cotton Mealybug or Phenacoccus solenopsis Which is characterized by the two black spots on it's back.

Phenacoccus solenopsis, the cotton mealybug or solenopsis mealybug, is a species of mealybug in the family Pseudococcidae. Having originated in North America, it has spread to other parts of the world and become a major pest of cotton crops. An infestation of this mealybug on cotton causes stunting of plants and yellowing, distortion and premature shedding of leaves; the presence of sooty mould reduces photosynthesis, bolls may not develop properly and yields of lint are reduced by an average of 35% in India.  Source: https://Wikipedia.org

Getting rid of these pests is by no means easy:

To get rid of mealybugs on houseplants, start by wiping the affected areas with a cotton swab dipped in rubbing alcohol to kill the adult mealybugs.
For light infestations, wash the plant with a diluted solution of dish soap and water, using a cloth or brush to remove the pests and honeydew.
If the infestation persists, apply neem oil or insecticidal soap directly to all plant surfaces, ensuring thorough coverage, especially under leaves. Repeat these treatments as necessary, keeping in mind that mealybugs can hide in crevices and may require multiple applications to completely eradicate.  Source: How to Remove Mealybugs



This is Mealybug. It looks like white fluffy clumps in the axils of the branches.
If the infestation really gets going some adults develop wings and can spread to other plants.
Mealybug is hard to control with soap and water or pesticides. The powdery wax layer they secrete protects them from control solutions.
See here and here for control methods and for more details
